# how to move one view to another in angular having different route file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to move one view to another in angular .Actually I am able to show first view .And in that view there is button .On click of button I am trying to go to next page But I am getting error on button click why ?

here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/2cMimMX6xS0rTB7lJOQx?p=preview

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('firstApp')
    .controller('firstcont', firstcont);

  firstcont.$inject = ['$scope',"$state"];
  function firstcont($scope,$state) {
    $scope.clickEvent=function(){
     $state.go('/second')
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Did you have a look at routing? Here is a nice writeup about it: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 1):

There is [updated working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lsNSCs9ledvbWJHy9HLm?p=preview) The state.go requires state name

```
function firstcont($scope,$state) {
    $scope.clickEvent=function(){
     // instead of this
     // $state.go('/second')
     // we need this
     $state.go('secondapp')
    }
}
```

because your state is defined as:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('secondapp', {
        url: '/second',
        ...
```

Check the [updated version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lsNSCs9ledvbWJHy9HLm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the plunker:-

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6v7ZUB1biVdWgeYpqDb?p=preview"

You need to change 
$state.go('/second') to $state.go('second')

And add the state 
.state('second', {
                url: '/second',
                views: {
                  app: { templateUrl: 'second.html' } 
                },
                controller:"firstcont"
            })
```